# SSIS - add upload date column after SSIS upload

Tags: sql-server, ssis, alter, getdate

I'm uploading a daily CSV file via a SSIS package to a SQL Server table and each time would like to insert a date column that states when the upload was complete. I'm thinking of putting in an Execute SQL Task after the Data Flow Task which uses a `ALTER TABLE` query with a `GETDATE()`.

Each time I run the SSIS package before the CSV data is uploaded the previous data is moved to an Archive table so there won't be any worry of overwriting data each time I insert a column.

Comment: Create a non nullable datetime column with a default of `GETDATE()` and it will populated automatically. You definitely don't want to use an `ALTER TABLE` - it's unecessary.

Comment: Are you completely recreating the destination table every time?   Otherwise, you should only need to ALTER it once to add the date column, not every time, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments.

What I have done is put in an Execute SQL Task and used the code

```
UPDATE [dbo].[CM25_Current] SET [Upload Date] = (GETDATE());
```

Comment: Did you try my suggestion in the comments? If you use a defatul then the field is automatically populated and no UPDATE is required. I highly recommend this be applied to all import and staging tables.

Comment: I'm very late to the party, here, but it's worth pointing out that setting a default value on the column won't work if you're appending to a table with existing rows and you can't dummy up default insert dates for the old data.  I'm trying to figure this out myself, and would love to see an SSDT-derived solution that doesn't involve schema changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a DATETIME column with default constraint set as GETDATE() will help your requirement.